# How can i continously move the view?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I want to create a simple app in which I want to make a road which is continuously animated. How can I do that?

Comment: If you abuse Cpt. Capslock, he will curse you and then you won't be able to create a application. Thats true, many people suffered this curse already, and they never wrote one line of code.

Comment: Yelling fixed. Earplugs removed.

Answer (score 1):

I used a UIScrollView. Then, set up an NSTimer that runs the following:

```
-(void)scroll{
    CGPoint currentPoint = playerStatsRect.contentOffset;
    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y + 1);
    [playerStatsRect setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:NO];

    if(scrollPoint.y == playerStatsRect.contentSize.height+5)//If we've reached the bottom, reset slightly past top, to give ticker look
    {
        [playerStatsRect setContentOffset:CGPointMake (0,-125)];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)